# IlGenerator Emit

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I'm playing around with `DynamicMethod` and trying to use `IL` to create some objects. I want to create the following very basic object:

```
new Queue<double>(new List<double>{100});
```

I have used ILDASM to see what `OpCodes` are needed to generate this. This is what ILDASM tells me:

```
IL_0000:  newobj     instance void class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<float64>::.ctor()
IL_0005:  dup
IL_0006:  ldc.r8     100.
IL_000f:  callvirt   instance void class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.List`1<float64>::Add(!0)
IL_0014:  newobj     instance void class [System.Collections]System.Collections.Generic.Queue`1<float64>::.ctor(class  [System.Runtime]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!0>)
IL_0019:  pop
IL_001a:  ret
```

This is what I am doing:

```
var dynMethod = new DynamicMethod("QueueMaker", typeof(Queue<double>), Type.EmptyTypes);
ILGenerator ilGen = dynMethod.GetILGenerator();
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(List<double>).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_R8, 100);
ilGen.EmitCall(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(List<double>).GetMethod("Add"), null);
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(Queue<double>).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<double>) }));
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
var returnFunc = (Func<Queue<double>>)dynMethod.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<Queue<double>>));
var queue = returnFunc();
```

I get exception `System.InvalidProgramException: 'Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.'` What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Looks like a dust fleck on your monitor when you look at the ildasm.exe output.  The distinction between `100` and `100.0` matters, you want to emit a double and not an int.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Two things:

(1)

```
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_R8, 100);
```

This is passing incorrect value type. Make sure you call the overload for `double`:

```
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_R8, (double)100); // or 100d
```

(2)

```
ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Pop);
```

Most probably ILDASM included that because here `new Queue<double>(new List<double>{100});` you are discarding the result, but this instruction is invalid when you need to return the result to the caller. The `Dup` instruction which saved the new `List<double>` instance on the evaluation stack has been consumed by the `Queue<double>` constructor call, so this removes the result from the stack, which at the end leads to invalid stack.

Remove that line and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

Do you realy want to play arround with Emit? You only want to create dynamic methods and in my opinion [Expressions Trees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/expression-trees/) are much more easier to use.

The result will be the same: a `Func<Queue<double>>`.

But first of all your code can be simplyfied. You call a [ctor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Collections_Generic_Queue_1__ctor_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable__0__) of `Queue` that takes a collection of elements. You only want to add the value `100` to the queue. Maybe the result will be the same as:

```
var result = new Queue<double>();
result.Enqueue(100);
return result;
```

That's the code to create this is:

```
// Getting types/methods
var queueItemType = typeof(double);
var queueType = typeof(Queue<>).MakeGenericType(queueItemType);
var queueEnqueueMethod = queueType.GetMethod(nameof(Queue<object>.Enqueue), new[] { queueItemType });

// Build the Func<>
var result = Expression.Parameter(queueType, "result");

var queueInstance = Expression.New(queueType);
var resultAssign = Expression.Assign(result, queueInstance);

var queueItem = Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(100, queueItemType), queueItemType);
var addCall = Expression.Call(result, queueEnqueueMethod, queueItem);

var body = new List<Expression>
{
    resultAssign,
    addCall,
    result  // The last line in body will be the result value of the Func<>.
};

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Queue<double>>>(Expression.Block(new[] { result }, body));
var func = lambda.Compile();

// Call it :-)
var queue = func();

Console.WriteLine(queue.Count);
Console.WriteLine(queue.Dequeue());
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/wn5D4K)

The code can be shortened by mergins some lines but I wrote every part in a single line for clearity.

Hint: You can call `ToString()` on every expression to see what will be generated with is very usefull to find errors.

The list can be created the same way if you realy need it.

**EDIT**

There is also a 'one-liner':

`() => new Queue<double>(Enumerable.Repeat(100.0, 1))`

This is the code that builds it:

```
// Getting types/methods
var itemType = typeof(double);
var repeatMethod = typeof(Enumerable).GetMethod(nameof(Enumerable.Repeat)).MakeGenericMethod(itemType);

var queueType = typeof(Queue<>).MakeGenericType(itemType);
var queueCtor = queueType.GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(IEnumerable<>).MakeGenericType(itemType) });

// Build the Func<>
var repeatCall = Expression.Call(repeatMethod, Expression.Constant(Convert.ChangeType(100, itemType)), Expression.Constant(1, typeof(int)));
var ctorCall = Expression.New(queueCtor, repeatCall);

var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Queue<double>>>(ctorCall);
var func = lambda.Compile();

// Call it :-)
var queue = func();

Console.WriteLine(queue.Count);
Console.WriteLine(queue.Dequeue());
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/4k9oOD)

Comment: Thanks Vera, this is really neat! I need to create an implementation of `IEnumerable<T>` to supply to constructor. The reason is that I want to substitute `Queue<T>` with a `Stack<T>` or `List<T>`, so I cannot depend on `Enqueue`.

Comment: @JohanP Yes you can change the type easyly in the "one-line" version :-)